# Using html ids to query mongoDB document

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I have been following a tutorial for building a CRUD app using mongoDB, Express, JQuery and Node.js.  I am now trying to add custom functionality and am failing to both edit and retrieve a document when I deviate from the code I mimicked. I am curious as to what is happening.  I have followed the delete and edit function which worked, to build a new edit function to allow me to update multiple fields and with a different UI.  I also want to get the document to use the fields to populate the HTML of various blocks in different parts of the website but I am failing to get the document to return.

I have assured that the get and put functions are working in Postman.

THIS IS WHAT IS WORKING:

```
app.put('/:id',(req,res) =>{
  const todoID = req.params.id;
  const userInput = req.body;

  db.getDB().collection(collection).findOneAndUpdate({_id: 
  db.getPrimaryKey(todoID)}, {$set: {todo: userInput.todo}}, 
 {returnOriginal : false},(err,result)=>{
  if(err)
       console.log(err);
  else{
      res.json(result);
  }
 });
});

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
  const userInput = req.body;
  db.getDB().collection(collection).insertOne(userInput, 
 (err,result)=>{
    if(err)
       console.log(err);
    else
      res.json({result: result, document: result.ops[0]});
  });
});


app.delete('/:id',(req,res)=>{
   const todoID = req.params.id;

  db.getDB().collection(collection).findOneAndDelete({_id : 
   db.getPrimaryKey(todoID)},(err,result)=>{
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
      else
       res.json(result);
     });
 });
```

This one is working in postman but not in my app:

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  const todoID = req.params.id;
  db.getDB().collection(collection).findOne({_id: 
  db.getPrimaryKey(todoID)}, (err,documents)=>{
     if(err)
      console.log(err);
     else{
      console.log(documents);
      res.json(documents);
     }
  });
});
```

THIS IS WORKING:

```
  const deleteShipment = (shipment, divShipmentID, deleteID) =>{
    let deleteBtn = $(`#${deleteID}`);
    deleteBtn.click(()=>{
      fetch(`/${shipment._id}`,{
        method: "delete"
      }).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
      }).then((data)=>{
          if(data.ok == 1){
            $(`#${divShipmentID}`).remove();
          }
      });
    });
  }
```

THIS IS NOT:

```
  const openEditOptions = (shipment, editID) =>{
    let editBtn = $(`#${editID}`);
    editBtn.click(()=>{
      console.log('activated');
      fetch(`/${shipment._id}`,{method: "get"}).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
      }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        readyEditForm(shipment);
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<button class="shipment-edit" id="edit_5c6759a05b4290e978136ea0" 
 type="button">Edit</button>

 <button type="button" class="shipment-delete" 
 id="delete_5c6759a05b4290e978136ea0">Delete</button>
```

I would expect that the edit button for that particular "shipment" would upon being clicked log to the console 'activated', and to return the shipment data in the console and as well as to the function readyEditForm.  Nothing happens.

Comment: Your editBtn fetch seems to make a get request when it should be put?

Comment: This sounds like it might actually be a jQuery question, right? If nothing is logging to the console, it sounds to me like you're not calling the `openEditOptions` (which could instead be named `registerEditOptionsClickHandler`) to attach the handler to the button. https://api.jquery.com/click/ has some more info about what's happening in there

Comment: @Countingstuff - so the name is deceiving.  I should have clarified that.  The desired effect is to actually have the edit button open a form that would populate with the former values.  I need the get request to get those values. then an UPDATE button appears and it would be .a put request once that is clicked.

Comment: @willis I have tested it using a jquery handler to the button and it shows the edit form as needed but it does not retrieve the previous values and populate the field with what is mongoDB.  There are work arounds but to be honest I am more interested in understanding for conceptual knowledge.  The fact the delete button is working as expected, when the code and fetch call are very similar, is what is driving me crazy.

Comment: OK, I'm a little confused about where the error is happening -- is the request to fetch data failing? Is the form not populated with data? How do requests look in the network tab?

Comment: @willis none is being logged when the button is being clicked.

Comment: OK, it really does sound to me like it's an issue with registering the click handler. If you're in the console, you should be able to query by editid the same way that you are in the code `$(`#${editID}`)` and see what you're attaching the handler to.

Comment: @willis i believe you're correct. The eventhandler is not showing in the console... the delete one is. What is odd is the characters are identical except for calling the editID rather than the deleteID.  It does log to the console when I do a direct query. Problem with it seems to be the function and applying it to multiple edit buttons.

Comment: I'd check what's being passed into `openEditOptions` to make sure the id is what you think it is. Putting a `debugger` statement there (or a log!) might be a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

`req.params` is a method to get the route parameters after a `:` in the path.

```
app.get('/:id' (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params.id); //prints whatever the user put in place of ":id"
});

app.get('/' (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params.id); //prints undefined
});
```

Once you fix that part of your code the rest of it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have updated the code as that is what I had initially thought it should be as well.  I think you're right... but I think Wilis is correct as well.. the issue is with the eventhandler.